# Include local html fragments within local html main container

Tags: html, include

**Background**

I want to stop using `Latex` for creating documentation and automatic reports for my applications and I would prefer to use `html+css` that I may later convert to `pdf` using [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) that allow for adding cover page, table of content, headers, footers, all in A4 separated pages.

[wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is light exe and supports for scripts/css for advanced document pre-processing / formatting. So, so far, so good, it all seems `html+css` is my best option to replace `Latex` ...

**Issue**

In order to ease maintenance and not to put all documentation content in a single file, I had initially thought to organize my **local** files like this:

```
doc/index.html

docs/includes/introduction.html
docs/includes/part1.html
docs/includes/part2.html

docs/resources/mystyle.css
docs/resources/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
```

And write main documentation `index.html` as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="./resources/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      // When document is ready, feed divs with real content
      $(document).ready(function() 
      {     
        $('#Introduction').load('./resources/introduction.html');
        $('#Part1').load('./resources/part1.html');
        $('#Part2').load('./resources/part2.html');         
      });       
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Introduction"></div>
    <div id="Part1"></div>
    <div id="Part2"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately doing this way, I receive a `XMLHttpRequest` error basically telling that it cannot load files because `cross-origin` is only supported for http, data, chrome, https etc... protocols *(?? even though all my files are local and `main.html` was also launched from local file system --so all same origin-- ??)*.

I tried many workarounds (`link rel=import`, `w3IncludeHTML`, use `iframe` and try to read content) they all fall in `cross-origin` issue.

**Question**

Is there an **easy/light** solution to merge all **local** html fragments in **local** `main.html` file (i.e no external `grep` or extra tools, just basic html+javascript) ?

NB1: I know I can change flags in chrome browser to allow `cross-origin` but would like to avoid this. First, for security reason. Second, because I can't do the same when sending files to `wkhtml2pdf` converter. Third because is not easy to provide documentation *as is* and say "just click `index.html` to open documentation in web-browser".

NB2: Documentation fragments is very likely to be just `<section>`, `<p>`, `<img>`, `<table>` elements all merged in body of `main.html` managing for css-formatting and other stuff in a single place.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Why can't you setup a local http server? With node.js for example it takes only a few lines.

Comment: @Supersharp I haven't found solution, so I put everything in a single html file (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40497481/684399). The reason I don't won't to use a local http server is that I'm trying to create automatic reports (all in html+css+javascript) so they can be easily be viewed and eventually printed to pdf or paper from any web-browser by customers (too complex to ask them to install local server just to view documents/reports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get local files in Firefox, using `XMLHttpRequest`.

It used to work with Chrome, but a "security" restriction [has been introduced](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416) since 2010 for local files.

Maybe you can suggest to use Firefox to all your customers...

---

A workaround (for Chrome) could be to load ressources as `<script>`, and get the content in multiline strings.

In *index.html*:

```
<script src="ressource1.js"></script>
...
```

In *ressource1.js*:

```
var fragment1 = `
     <section>
         HTML content for part 1 
     </section>`
document.querySelector( '#target1' ).innerHTML = fragment1
```

Ressources are kept in separate files (in form of JavaScript) and injected in the main HTML document.

---

Maybe it would be worth to provide an [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) application along with your documentation files to browse it without web server.

Actually it's a node.js web server packed with a chromuim browser. It targets most platfoms and you just need your HTML/JS/CSS skills. By the way you could also integrate a PDF library inside.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround ... I indeed now suggest to customers to use firefox because repeating table headers/footers [doesn't work with chrome when printing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40497481/684399) ... I may also force them to use firefox for reading, so it can ease maintenance on my side with multiple fragments as [chrome also has restrictions on that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40264503/684399).